# Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId is short ? why?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I have a question. Outlook add-in.

The itemId value is strange from 3 days ago. We are using the office.js provided by Microsoft.
It was developed as an official document.

Issues
The results for Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId code are different on mobile and PC.

1. Mobile
   AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC/EBBBBBBiI2N+M9RJ0CDShuowvXKcwACJekCOwAA
2. PC
   Result: AAMkAGM1ZDc2YjFjLWExODUtNGVkNC1hNDBBBBABEAMSxr1XgSL8NM2 + Hy8n2BwByK7vlr7ySQpFsplYmphCiAAAAAEMAACIjY34z1EnQINKG6jC9cpzAAIl6LODAAA =

The same code, but the results are different.

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of entry IDs:

1. A short-term entry identifier is assigned by a service provider to an object when the identifier must be constructed quickly and does not need to last over time or distance. The uniqueness of a short-term entry identifier is guaranteed only over the life of the current session on the current workstation. Typically, a short-term entry identifier is valid only until the object that it represents is released. Clients quickly acquire, use, and discard short-term entry identifiers. For the most part, they can be used in the same manner as long-term entry identifiers.
2. A long-term entry identifier is assigned by a service provider to an object when an object requires an identifier with a prolonged lifespan. Long-term entry identifiers are always valid for weeks or months and can be valid on other workstations, depending on the provider. The long-term identifiers created by address book providers for custom recipients are universally valid. Long-term entry identifiers must be unique across all message stores in the active profile; therefore, when a message or folder is copied from one message store to another, it must be assigned a new entry identifier. When a message store object is moved, the message store provider that implements the move determines whether the original entry identifier will remain valid. Some service providers assign new entry identifiers to moved objects; others do not. If there is a change, the new entry identifier will be included in the information passed to clients when they are notified of the move.

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly the same problem.

Worse it that it is currently different on one mobile device to another.  i.e. some mobile devices are still returning the long code and consequently are working.

I don't overly care about getting a 'short code' but you can NOT reference the object using the 'short code'.

Therefor 'short code' = Broken Microsoft Outlook on mobile devices.

This is not a "minor" issue as it has rendered our plugin inoperable on mobile devices.

Comment: Not an answer, you should write the solution

Comment: Rumour has it that MS is aware and is working on it.
NOTE: This is hearsay/rumour only as it is second hand information and I haven't had a direct conformation of this.